# Return index and values as dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I am trying to return non zero values and their indices in dictionary format.
For example if I have `[0 3 0 6 9]`, the output would be `d['ind'] = [1,3,4]` and `d['val'] = [3,6,9]`
This is what I have tried so far.

```
def inds_vals(x):
    
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    j=0
    for i in x:
        if i != 0:
            d.update({'inds': j, 'vals':i})
            j = j+1
    return
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def inds_vals(x):
    #assert type(x) is list
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    for i, v in enumerate(x):
        if v != 0:
            d['inds'].append(i)
            d['vals'].append(v)
    return d
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you ask:

```
def inds_vals(x):
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    j=0
    for j,i in enumerate(x):
        if i != 0:
            d['inds']+=[j]
            d['vals']+=[i]
            j = j+1
    return d
print(inds_vals([0,3,0,6,9]))
```